# Preferred 3d model format of THREE.JS

Tags: 3d, file-format, three.js

What is the preferred 3d model format of THREE.JS which is widely used by 3d modelling softwares (can export to that format). I ask this, because I have my 3d models in an own unique format, and would like to use them in THREE.JS. While I could write an own loader, but I think it's better to convert them to a standard format.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

We have our own [JSON Geometry format](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Geometry-format-4).

You can use these:

- [Editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) (drag your object into the window, select it and select `File/Export Geometry`)
- [Blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender)
- [Python script from OBJ to JSON](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py)

Comment: Some of those links are out of data. Could you fix this?

Comment: Does the JSONLoader give substantial performance improvements over creating the scene using javascript only?

Comment: @DanMacumber no... if anything, that version of the format is probably slower... next version of the format (4) should change this...

Comment: It is still actual? For the future development is the JSON format best option? thx

Comment: Is there a way to go from .step or other CAD formats to this JSON format?

Comment: Per [three.js | Loading 3D models](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Loading-3D-models), we recommend glTF when possible. Several other formats like FBX, OBJ, COLLADA, and SEA3D are also well supported.

Answer (score 8):

The online 3D editor http://Clara.io can also export to the various ThreeJS JSON formats.  http://Clara.io supports importing more than 20 different formats, including FBX, Collada, 3DS, STL and DXF, so it can be used as a general conversion tool.

Comment: Just tried importing an object from TurboSquid to Clara.io. It doesn't work, the object imported looks nothing like the object in Three.js. I just paid $10 for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think that three.js does not have prefered 3d model. Personaly I prefer wavefront object (obj).

Answer (score 1):

export the model  from clara.io or others providers 
then import into https://threejs.org/editor/
so you can tried some format of models